# iterating on pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I have two csv files. file1 looks like this:
[file1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e59Nd.png)

and file 2 looks like this:[file2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrvUg.png)

I need to write a script (I am using pandas dataframe) that fiils the  column with "Yes" every time a Brewer and Microbrewers Licensees name is in the file1's  column.
And if a Brewer and Microbrewers Licensees is not on the file1, add is to the file1 including the county and the address (parsed of each columns on file1)

so far I got:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
factories=[]

file1=pd.read_csv("CraftBeverageData.csv")
file2=pd.read_csv("brewers.csv")
beers1 = pd.DataFrame(file1)
for i in beers1["Name"]:
    factories.append(i)

for name in brewers["Brewer and Microbrewers Licensees"]:
    if name in  factories:
        beers1["Brewer and Microbrewers Licensees"]="Yes"
```

Comment: Hey @qqqqqqq, try to post your dataframes as code, so it's easier for us to help you. Also what have you tried? post some of your code

Answer (score 0):

As I undestand, *Brewer and Microbrewers Licensees* column in
*CraftBeverageData.csv* has been filled as an expected result,
but it should actually be filled with data, based on the presence of *Name* column
in *CraftBeverageData.csv* with the first column in the other DataFrame.

The code should be something like below:

```
# Read DataFrames
beverages = pd.read_csv("CraftBeverageData.csv")
brewers = pd.read_csv("brewers.csv")
# Processing
licNames = brewers['Brewer and Microbrewers Licensees'].values
beverages['Brewer and Microbrewers Licensees'] =\
    beverages.Name.apply(lambda name: 'Yes' if name in licNames else '')
```

I couldn't test this code, because you did not provide source data
in a form that could be easy copied.

Another, more concise solution, based on *Numpy* (after you read both DataFrames):

```
licNames = brewers['Brewer and Microbrewers Licensees']
beverages['Brewer and Microbrewers Licensees'] =\
    np.where(beverages.Name.isin(licNames), 'Yes', '')
```

Comment: Hey @Valdi_Bo This actualy worked, thanks. I have never used "lambda" before. I had no idea it was a thing

Comment: But how do I add a Brewer and Microbrewers Licensees to the beverages dataframe if its not there. how do I parse the address part as well?

Comment: My code (both versions) contain *beverages['Brewer and Microbrewers Licensees'] = ...* It means that if this column was not in the DataFrame, it will be created. Otherwise its previous content will be overwritten.